# What are the number of ways of arranging $5$ persons on the circumference of a circular table?

Tags: logic, permutations, combinations

If $5$ persons $A,B,C,D,E$  are to be arranged on the circumference of a circular table then in how many distinct ways can this be done??
I tried to do it but I am not getting right answer.. Here is what I did..
I made this neat diagram
-[image]
Now for the

- first place marked as( ($1$) in the pic)
  five choices/options $A,B,C,D,E$ are there..similarly..
- for the $2$ nd place -- $4$ choices are there.
- Now for the third pways  -- $3$ options are there.
- and for fourth place --2 options/choices are there
- and lastly only -- $1$ choice is there for 5th place..

Thus by using *The fundamental principle of counting* ..the total number of ways is $=5×4×3×2×1$ that is $120$ but the answer given is $24$..what is wrong in this process..I am not able to see any mistake here..
NOTE:I think most of users here will
Mark this question as duplicate..but I have seen some of those other questions..but most of them are very hard in front of this very basic question...I also found a nearly similar question which used a formula $(n-1)!$ That is $4!$ here which gives the right answer ..but I wanted to solve this question using the most basic method that is (fundamental principle of counting)

EDIT: Most of the answers here are divide $120$ by $5$ to get the right answer..but can anyone please explain a little bit.. .as to ...why?? I should divide by $5$..

Comment: In your process of counting, you have to consider the fact that the "first place" could have been any of the $5$ chairs.

Comment: You have $5!=120$ ways to order them, and each way is symmetrically identical to $4$ other ways. Hence there are $120/5=24$ distinct ways to do it.

Comment: The two answers below explain it pretty well. Within that group of $120$ permutations, you have equivalence classes. Each class contains $5$ permutations which are symmetrical to each other, i.e., you can rotate any one of them and get any of the others. Those classes are also **disjoint** from each other (each class contains $5$ **unique** permutations). Hence the total number of distinct orderings is $120/5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on problem but Here ABCDE is the same as BCDEA, CDEAB, DEABC and EABCD (because of the circular table, the place's number is not really important, but who is next to whom is important). So yes you have to divide by 5.

So there is $\frac{120}{5}=24$.

Comment: What..how..are ..ABCDE is the same as BCDEA, CDEAB, DEABC and EABCD ..because it is a circular table..so what??...

Comment: Our purpose here..is not just to make the persons $A,B,C,D,E$ ocuppy one seat each and be happy..because in this case..only 1 possibility will be there..as obviously ..in all the cases everyone is sitting ..so then what was.. the need to solve the question..we could have directly said..that all the cases are same..but no..here the fact that which person is ocuppying which position matters also.... So that is $A$ occupying 5th chair..in BCDEA and ocuppying the third chair in DEABC are not same..they are different!!

Comment: Because it's a circular table.ABCDE is the same as BCDEA because it only depends on how you look at the table. A will be between B and E in both case. So you are arranging people the same way.

Comment: OK...I see the relative positions of the persons are not changing ..so all ABCDE, BCDEA, CDEAB, DEABC and EABCD .. are the same...Thanks...

Comment: But if I say all the chairs on which A,B,C,D,E are supposed to sit are.. different... And they are numbered/painted..differently..then would the answer have been same(120)..or differnt(24)??

Comment: It depends on how the problem is describing it. If it explains that chairs are different (painted differently for exemple or if they were in line instead of a circle), yes the answer would have been 120.

Answer (score 0):

Note that circular shifts do not change the sitting arrangements, hence, the answer is $\frac{120}{5}=24$.